# Disable interactive logins in bash scripts

Tags: bash, ssh

I have an SSH key based authentication setup for some deployment script. But there is a chance that the authentication files are not setup properly at some point. I don't want my shell scripts to ask for passwords, I want them to fail immediately.

Using

> ssh  -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no
>   -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes  test@host

or some thing along those lines does not work. I do not want to change configuration files since the script can be executed from any where.

Comment: Can't you simply allow only PubkeyAuth in the sshd config on the host?

Comment: nopes, every thing has to be in the command it's self.

Comment: openssh has batchmode for this: http://serverfault.com/questions/61915/how-do-i-make-ssh-fail-rather-than-prompt-for-a-password-if-the-public-key-authe

Comment: openssh has batchmode for this: http://serverfault.com/questions/61915/how-do-i-make-ssh-fail-rather-than-prompt-for-a-password-if-the-public-key-authe

Comment: @ott as ***answer***, not comment...

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried, it was converted into a comment because it was to trivial. :-)

Comment: @ott-- Then add some explanation. What command line switch, example command line, quote from the man page, something like that. It's the correct answer and you deserve to post it.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem and found the answer here:

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/47179

Basically, openssh used keyboard-interactive to implement challenge-repsonse. So if either of these options are set to "yes", then keyboard-interactive gets set to "yes" in the code. You have to set both to "no" in order to get the behavior you want.

I had to do:

`ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no`

Of course, the `BatchMode=yes` setting would take care of all of these for you and future proof you against any new user interactive authentication methods in the future.